# Problems from reading file

Tags: java, file, arraylist, hashmap

I have a problem with one of my classes in a project.
I tried to read all the lines from a file but when I print that it shows me less than the half lines.
What can I do for that?

Comment: You can paste your code here for example ;-)

Comment: "_Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]._"

Comment: are you aware that we can not help you until you provide us A) the Code and  maybe the file!

Answer (score 0):

Use below code file reading and printing in console :-

```
 public class ReadFileExample {

    private static final String FILENAME = "E:\\test\\filename.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader br = null;
        FileReader fr = null;

        try {

            fr = new FileReader(FILENAME);
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            String sCurrentLine;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            try {

                if (br != null)
                    br.close();

                if (fr != null)
                    fr.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {

                ex.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME));` `fr = new FileReader(FILENAME);
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);` why do the same thing 2 times?

Comment: By the way, this could be done in one line in Java 8 ;) and half this in Java 7

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.